# Change OSX fullscreen to open on left most instead of right most desktop

Tags: macos, fullscreen

When opening a new window in native fullscreen mode OSX creates a new "desktop" for the window, I'd like all new windows to open to the "first" desktop which means I can go straight into it instead of needing to swipe through every single current desktop.

The first screenshot is the current behaviour. I'd like the second to happen. Notice "Desktop 2" as the new one I opened.

[image: What currently happens]
[image: What I want]